# SSI not working in html

Tags: html, ssi

I've been through all the topics on here and have tried everything but my SSI code is not pulling the html page like it should...

What i have already tried:

- confirmed with godaddy that SSI is enabled
- tried both `<!--#include virtual="\menus\menu.html" -->` & `<!--#include file="\menus\menu.html" -->`
- tried changing "menu.html" to "menu.shtml"

i'm stuck...what's going on?

here is my html:

```
<body>
<!--#include virtual="http://unifiedforunifat.com/menus/menu.html" -->
<div id="include">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: If you say "not pulling the html page", do you mean the SSI parts are not handled at all (you get the comments back in the resulting html) or that there is just nothing included? Do other SSI commands work, like `echo`?

Comment: hey     thanks for responding....i have tested the SSI with this simple command: <!--#config timefmt="%A" --> <!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" --> and it worked

Comment: OK... I'm really not an shtml guru, you know. Ehm, what if you put the include file in the same directory as the shtml file?

Comment: hey   i got it working....seems godaddy doesn't like the virtual command and then you have to have to the corresponding .html file in the same directory as the html file....thanks for helping mr. lister!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are including the external web address of your script. Not only does that violate the point of having scripts on the *server side*, but random people can view the script if it's accessible that way.

Try

```
<!--#include virtual="/menus/menu.html" -->
```

It seems your slashes are the wrong way around. The `\` character is the Windows filesystem slash, not the standard `/` slash for most technologies and Linux/Mac OS filesystems.

If `virtual` doesn't work, you should be able to use:

```
<!--#include file="/menus/menu.html" -->
```

According to http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html, `virtual` specifies an included request, whereas `file` specifies an included file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can edit the `.htaccess` file to allow for them to be in separate folders (and inherently more tidy).

Add the following command to the first line of your `.htaccess` file in the `root`:

```
AddType text/x-server-parsed-html .html .htm
```